# Sql server use pivot

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Here is my Database structure :

> [image]

I want to display data like the following :

> [image]

How can I do it ? Should I use pivot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for this. There are two ways to do this with PIVOT, either a Static Pivot where you code the columns to transform or a Dynamic Pivot which determines the columns at execution.

Static Pivot:

```
select *
from
(
  select dt, username, product,
    'product' 
      + cast(row_number() 
               over(partition by username order by product) as varchar(10)) productNum
  from yourtable
) x
pivot
(
  min(product)
  for productNum in ([product1], [product2], [product3])
) p
order by dt
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8eac/13)

Dynamic Pivot:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = 
    STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + Quotename('product' 
              + cast(row_number() 
               over(partition by username order by product) as varchar(10)))
             from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query 
    = 'SELECT dt, username,' + @cols + ' from 
       (
        select dt, username, product,
           ''product''
            + cast(row_number() 
               over(partition by username order by product) as varchar(10)) productNum
        from yourtable
       ) x
       pivot 
       (
          min(product)
          for productNum in (' + @cols + ')
       ) p 
        order by dt'

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8eac/12)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use pivot.

But unless you know how many products there will be, you will need to use a dynamic pivot - something [like this](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-2008/dynamic-pivot-in-tsql/).